# How to make JavaFX ScrollPane keep scrolling if a button inside ScrollPane is dragged?

Tags: java, javafx, touch, scrollpane

I have a JavaFX ScrollPane inside a JFXPanel in my java project. This project will be in touch monitors with no keyboards so I need to emulate a touch-screen scroll.

The problem is; if I drag the mouse in the ScrollPane it works fine but if I drag the mouse where there are buttons, it can't scroll (and the idea is the ScrollPane will be filled with buttons with no space between them).

[The white part and the buttons are inside ScrollPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odN4m.png)

Here is the part that create the ScrollPane in my code.

```
    private static Scene createScene(int wS, int hS) {
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        FlowPane flowpane = new FlowPane();
        
        scrollPane.setCache(true);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scrollPane.setPannable(true);

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            flowpane.getChildren().add((new ButtonProduct(wS, "Apple " + (i+1)));
        
        scrollPane.setContent(flowpane);
        Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(scrollPane);
        return (scene);
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I added a MouseEvent when the button is dragged but i don't know how to "make the scrollpane selected" to move it.

```
    public ButtonProduct(int wS, String t) {
        this.setText(t);
        this.setMinSize((int) (wS*sizeW), (int) (wS*sizeW));
        this.setPrefSize((int) (wS*sizeW), (int) (wS*sizeW));
        this.setMaxSize((int) (wS*sizeW), (int) (wS*sizeW));
        this.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Dragged Button");
                e.consume();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What's Swing got to do with this?

Comment: A shot in the dark, but my assumption is that you would need to capture the mouse click event, determine if it's a gesture (like sliding the finger instead of just tapping it), and react accordingly. But the question itself is a bit too broad here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, this is the code for a Button(Node) inside a ScrollPane. **BUT** you need to restore the Button Event for a better performance which is not developed on the next code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;

public class ButtonProduct extends Button {
    private static double sizeW = .075;
    //Constructor
    public ButtonProduct(ScrollPane sC, int wS, String t) {
        this.setText(t);
        this.setMinSize((int) (wS*sizeW), (int) (wS*sizeW));
        this.setPrefSize((int) (wS*sizeW), (int) (wS*sizeW));
        this.setMaxSize((int) (wS*sizeW), (int) (wS*sizeW));
        this.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                ((Button) e.getSource()).setEventDispatcher(sC.getEventDispatcher());
                sC.requestFocus();
                e.consume();
            }
        });
    }
}
```